# HTML hidden tags vs JS createElement

Tags: javascript, html

It is a YouTube iframe and some divs (about 5 or less) which display video data as title, time and a progress bar and a random video section at the bottom. If the video doesn't exists these (title, time and progress) divs should not be displayed and then if the user click in a random video these divs should be displayed again.

So is it faster to `generate hidden tags and show them` when the button is clicked with JS or do not generate them at all and create using `createElement()` ?

What are the pros/ cons? And of course which is faster?

And does that `delta time` really matter?

Comment: I would just show the tags using css. it really depends what exactly you are trying to do. can you provide more information about the scenario? I doubt you need to be worried about performance unless you are adding thousands of elements.

Comment: also, unless you are talking about a 404 on ajax, normally you'd just display a simple 404 html page and leave it at that.

Comment: set up your page with all the html to display what you want, then use css and javascript to hide/show based on if the video loads, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are good options, but the difference between them is that HTML is parsed a lot faster than JS since it does not need to be interpreted after the page loads. But javascript will also lockdown the element so that it cannot be manually altered.

For example, this `answer` you are reading will take about 2 ms to load onto the page... but if you did:

```
var answer = createElement('div');
answer.innerHTML = "Both are good options...";
document.body.appendChild(answer);
```

each line would take about 5 ms, adding up to 15 ms in total. Making it a little slower. But it wont be drastic if you only do it to a few elements.

now if you are in chrome/firefox/safari try doing `CTRL+SHIFT+I` or `F12`... you should see developer tools popup.. and if you set this answer to hidden, you will not see this answer. but you can still alter the code of it. and when you unhide it, it will show you the new code. Javascript will prevent this from happening, but if the element is already made, or has a lot of content in it    then just use `hidden`

Comment: I don't think this answer is accurate. 15ms for 3 lines of javascript? where did you get that? that sounds absurd.

also, I'm not sure what you mean by javascript locking down an element. no elements get locked by javascript. they are easily manipulated with javascript.

Comment: So what is better to use? Create them from server side and hide or create  with js? There are a few divs about 4 or five with just two words (a song title and a progress bar) @Timmerz

Comment: javascript is normally used for dynamic pages. it sounds like you just need something simple, so I would just have html and hide/show with css. I think you should provide more context about what you're trying to do.